# ValidateAntiForgeryToken in override controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken, overriding

I have three controllers but `Controller1` inherited from `Controller2` and `Controller2` inherited of the `Controller3`.

for example

```
public class Controller1 : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(MyClass test)
    {
...

public class Controller2 : Controller1
{
...

public class Controller3 : Controller2
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public override ActionResult Create(MyClass test)
...
```

also in View add

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

when have one control and no inherited good work but when use inherit and override method the ValidateAntiForgeryToken get error.

validationAntiforgeryToken is not valid and get Error:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is
>   not present.
>
> [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form
>   field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.]

...

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with your Controller-hierarchy, it's because you don't have an AntiForgeryToken in the request (as the error says).

To do so, add the following to your view (inside the form) that posts to the Controller:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: Are you sure you added it inside the form?

Comment: yes I am sure you can testing
when you have one controller and no inherited from other controller working good but in inherited get error validation

Comment: oh 
I am finding problem.
I use ajax for posting and in ajax set contentType:'' and datatype:''.
I change tow parameters and repaire bug
thanks for all...

Comment: Yes, that would be an issue. If you use Ajax take a look at this post from Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx